# Remove large gap between images in Linear Layout Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview, firebase-storage, android-linearlayout

I have a program that is adding imageViews to a linear layout within a horizontal scrollview, but each image ends up with a very large gap between each one. This looks terrible, and I want to reduce the gap between them, just so that they are closer together. This is how big the gap between each image is right now

[image: This is the size of the current gap]

Here is the code where I am adding them into the layout. I have tried changing the scaletype of the imageviews but I couldn't find a way to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public void addPicturesToView(){
        LinearLayout pictureLayout = findViewById(R.id.qrImageLinearLayout);
        docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                List<String> imageList = (List<String>) documentSnapshot.get("Images");
                for(String imageString : imageList){
                   StorageReference storRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(imageString);
                    Task<byte[]> task = storRef.getBytes(1000000).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(byte[] imageBytes) {
                            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
                            ImageView qrImage = new ImageView(QRcodeViewerActivity.this);
                            qrImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            qrImage.setLayoutParams(params);
                            pictureLayout.addView(qrImage);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return;
            }
        });
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue, by setting AdjustViewBounds to true and adding padding I was able to make it look proper.

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
                            ImageView qrImage = new ImageView(QRcodeViewerActivity.this);
                            qrImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            qrImage.setLayoutParams(params);
                            qrImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                            qrImage.setPadding(5,0,5, 0);
                            pictureLayout.addView(qrImage);
```

[image]